# Turn a few tags to one

Tags: html, tags

I have this code in my page. I find it very long to write all of these tags in order to write a few words. Is there any other way to shorten it to a simple tag, while keeping the div, ul, and li activated?

```
<div class="code">
  <ul class="codeline">
    <li>print(a)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Much thanks!

Comment: You want to keep it the way it is, without keeping it the way it is…?! If you have some server-side language or even client-side Javascript, you could use those to automatically change the markup around the text. What do you have available?

Comment: It's all about semantics, why have you put a single item in a list?  why not just put it in the top level div?  Also, if you can't be bothered to type full tags, why not get an editor that auto-complete's them for you when you type.   Other than that, just stop being lazy

Comment: single item list is strange, div holding a single list is strange, you can just use a div with code and codeline class, and style it a bit more to mare it look exactly as you want. so the short answer is no, you cant keep div, ul and li activated while removing them.

Answer (score 0):

HTML provides no such functionality. You need to find or write a tool.

There are many editors which will expand shortcodes into larger snippets of HTML. There are many template libraries you could use with many programming languages.